# Create a query with multiple databases

Tags: postgresql, oracle, federated-table

Let say I have DB1, a database in PostgreSQL, and DB2, a database in Oracle.

How can I make a query joining these databases?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [foreign data wrappers](https://laurenz.github.io/oracle_fdw/) in Postgres to make Oracle tables appear like [local tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createforeigntable.html) in Postgres.

Then you can use the Oracle tables in a query running in Postgres and join them to the "real"  Postgres tables in a single query.

A list of foreign data wrappers (not included with Postgres itself) is available in the [Postgres Wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Foreign_data_wrapper)

Comment: I think that "DB2" in this case is actually referring to an Oracle database, not the IBM product - the OP could have used DB_A and DB_B or similar. +1 for the Foreign Data Wrappers - better than my answer (clean slipped my mind!).

Comment: @Vérace: good point, you are probably right. I removed that

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQLDeveloper to connect to [multiple different servers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22299552/470530) using JDBC? You may have to store resultsets in temporary storage!

You could obviously use the same approach with Java, again with JDBC.

And you could make use of Oracle's "[Database Heterogeneous Connectivity User's Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e11050/whatsnew.htm#CJACHDID)".

So, you have a number of different strategies open to you - you'll have to go with the one that best suits your skillset and/or budget. And no, it's not a dumb question - nobody was born knowing the ins and outs of database connectivity!